# Как сравнить два csv файла

Tags: c#, csv, сравнение

Есть 2 **csv** файла с содержимым

**1.csv**

```
spain;russia;japan
italy;russia;france
```

**2.csv**

```
spain;russia;japan
india;iran;pakistan
```

Считываю оба файла и заношу их содержимое в список

```
var lst1= File.ReadAllLines("1.csv").ToList();
var lst2= File.ReadAllLines("2.csv").ToList();
```

Затем я ищу уникальные элементы из обоих списков

```
var rezList = lst1.Except(lst2).Union(lst2.Except(lst1)).ToList();
```

В `rezlist` у нас следюущие данные.

```
[0] = "italy;russia;france"
[1] = "india;iran;pakistan"
```

Теперь же я хочу сравнить оба csv-файла по второй и третьей колонке. Как мы выдими разделители колонок у нас `;`

```
class StringLengthEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
    {

        public bool Equals(string x, string y)
        {
            return (x.Split(';')[1] == y.Split(';')[1] && x.Split(';')[2] == y.Split(';')[2]);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(string obj)
        {
            return obj.Split(';')[1].GetHashCode();
        }
    }

 StringLengthEqualityComparer stringLengthComparer = new StringLengthEqualityComparer();
 var rezList = lst1.Except(lst2,stringLengthComparer ).Union(lst2.Except(lst1,stringLengthComparer),stringLengthComparer).ToList();
```

Вопрос. Как правильно составить класс `StringLengthEqualityComparer` чтобы он искал уникальные значения по двум колонкам?

Comment: нет не дубль...

Comment: Структура файла заранее известна? Количество полей хотя бы

Comment: количество колонок всегда статично. На данный момент я могу спокойно сравнивать по одной колонке, но вот если колонок 2. Как тогда использовать GetHashCode?

Comment: @Radzhab MD5 не рассматриваете для сравнения 2х колонок ?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Вы можете составить единый массив из элементов 2 и 3 колонок и потом получить хеш-код от этого массива. Это чем-то не подходит?

Comment: А обязательно нужен StringLengthEqualityComparer  ? Почему-бы регулярками не вырезать из 1 и 2 списка все лишнее? Получаешь список вида : [Исходное значение],[значение двух колонок через запятую] и выполняешь сравнение через второе поле.

Comment: Ваш `StringLengthEqualityComparer ` мне не особо нравится, точнее то, как он реализован. Скажите, что Вы хотите получить в результате? Может быть Вам предложат другой подход.

Comment: я хочу чтобы операции distinct, union и except работали не по всей строке, а по отдельным его "колонкам".  Под колонками понимается текст разделенный ; (точка с запятой)

Comment: Т.е. Вас отдельно интересует сравнение строчек по отдельным столбцам?

Первый вариант - отказаться от `IEqualityComparer` вообще. Написать все в процедурном стиле.
Второй вариант - завести столько `IEqualityComparer`, сколько у Вас столбцов. Они все будут отличаться ф-цией `GetHashCode`
Третий вариант - написать универсальный `IEqualityComparer` ДЛЯ ОДНОГО СТОЛБЦА, а далее сравнивать по каждому из столбцов. Строки идентичны если lst1_row1 == lsr2_row1 && lst1_row2 == lsr2_row2 && ... и т.д. сколько столбцов.

Напишите, ЧТО конкретно хотите - что есть конечный результат алгоритма.

Comment: Не очень понятно, чем вас не устраивает ваша собственная реализация `StringLengthEqualityComparer`?

Comment: @andreycha из комментария выше: _На данный момент я могу спокойно сравнивать по одной колонке, но вот если колонок 2. Как тогда использовать GetHashCode?_

Comment: @Grundy Вам вообще не нужен метод `GetHashCode`. Выбросьте и его и его реализацию, всё будет работать.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, если выбросить - не будет :-) потому что интерфейс будет не полностью имплементирован, не говоря уже о том, что автор вопроса не я :-)

Comment: @Grundy, и правда. Простите, ответил, не проверив.

Comment: @Radzhab, на `GetHashCode` есть только одно ограничение: для одинаковых объектов он должен давать одинаковые значения. То есть если у вас есть строки "x;y;z" и "u;y;z" и вы считаете их равными, потому что равны 2-я и 3-я колонка, можете писать `obj.Split(';')[1].GetHashCode() + obj.Split(';')[2].GetHashCode()`, будет работать как надо.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, не, не будет, складывать хэшкоды вообще не очень, потому что в данном случае он будет одинаковым для `a;b` и `b;a` что неверно, так как столбцы имеют разное значение

Comment: @Grundy да, будет. Хеш может быть одинаковым для разных объектов, это не проблема. Коллизии по хеш-кодам возможны и предусмотрены в реализации хеш-таблиц. Действительно важно, чтобы для одинаковых объектов хеш-коды были одинаковыми.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko сложение? Этапять! Нормальный алгоритм хэширования не должен на ровном месте создавать коллизии. У вашего же "алгоритма" их будет непростительно много. Например, хэшкоды для пар "d;r", "c;s", "b;t", "a;u" будут равны.

Comment: @Grundy так шо, весь вопрос в том, как правильно написать `GetHashCode()` для двух значений?

Comment: @andreycha, скорее _зачем вообще этот GetHashCode_ нужен если все равно вся логика в Equals

Comment: @MarkShevchenko полегче, любезный. Я хоть сразу и сменил формулировку своего комментария на более нейтральную, однако не использовал оскорбительные слова даже в оригинале. А ничего оскорбительного в том, чтобы глупую идею назвать глупой, я не вижу. Всего хорошего вам.

Comment: @andreycha, речь шла конкретно про фразу "вы видимо про коллизии только краем уха слышали". Я теперь что, должен доказывать, что нет, не краем уха, что моё предложение вполне себе хорошее, потому что позволяет быстро решить задачу и двигаться дальше? Под сомнение поставлена моя профессиональная репутация, причём просто так, походя. Это некорректно.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko ну так я же вам привел конкретные примеры. Даже на маленьком наборе значений (буквы алфавита) ваш "алгоритм" (позволю себе продолжить писать его в кавычках) дает много коллизий.

Comment: @Grundy на корректность результата это действительно не влияет. Но если строк (и, соответственно значений) будет много, то при нереализованном или неверно реализованном `GetHashCode()` вся польза от `Set<T>`, которым пользуется метод `Except()`, испарится, и мы получим линейный перебор по сути.

Comment: @andreycha И что? Ваш набор из букв алфавита как раз нетипичен, количество коллизий на словах будет гораздо меньше. Кроме того, ну вот будет коллизий например на 30% больше — насколько сильно это повлияет на производительность? Вы посчитали, проверили? Пусть производительность просядет и на реальных данных вместо 2,3 сек будет уходить 2,7 сек, это что, смертельно или плохо? Почему вы позволяете себе сразу приступать к оскорблениям на основании чисто умозрительных представлений?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Интерфейс `IEqualityComparer<T>` предоставляет возможность расширения или замены логики сравнения объектов. Он используется, например, в таких структурах, как `Dictionary<K, V>` и `HashSet<T>`, а также в некоторых методах, которые активно пользуются сравнением объектов (как например использованный вами метод расширения `Except()`).

Как известно, для того, чтобы иметь возможность корректно сравнивать объекты, в них должны быть переопределены методы `Equals()` и `GetHashCode()`, причем должны соблюдаться следующие условия:

- стандартные условия для равенства (например, транзитивность)
- два равных объекта должны давать одинаковое значение хэшкода

(При этом два разных объекта могут иметь равные хэшкоды -- это называется коллизией и должно случаться как можно реже.)

Оба этих метода активно используются структурами `Dictionary<K, V>`, `HashSet<T>`, а также внутренним классом [`Set<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9c10b234c0932864,references), который используется в методе `Except()`.

В случае, когда мы не хотим или не имеем возможности изменять логику сравнения для существующих типов, на помощь нам и приходит интерфейс `IEqualityComparer<T>` -- вместо вызовов методов `Equals()` и `GetHashCode()` у самих объектов, эти методы вызываются у компаратора. Именно поэтому этот интерфейс содержит оба метода, а не один `Equals()`. А также именно поэтому реализация компаратора должна соблюдать обозначенные выше условия.

---

Приведенная вами реализация компаратора дает корректные результаты сравнения, однако при большом объеме данных может свести на нет все преимущества быстрой работы метода `Except()`. Для пар `a;b` и `a;c` выдастся одинаковый хэшкод, они попадут в одну корзину внутри `Set<T>`, что ухудшает показатели скорости работы (подробнее читайте в статьях о том, как работают хэш-таблицы).

Поэтому правильная реализация должна использовать те же поля, которые используются в `Equals()`, т.е. колонки 1 и 2 (про хэш-функции также читайте в статьях о хэш-таблицах). Например:

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
    var valuesArray = obj.Split(';')
    int hashcode = valuesArray[1].GetHashCode();
    hashcode = hashcode * 31 + valuesArray[2].GetHashCode();
    return hashcode;
}
```

На этом реализация компаратора закончена.

---

Однако в целом производительность такого решения оставляет желать лучшего. Поскольку вы вызываете `Except()` дважды, то для каждой пары строк из обоих файлов методы компаратора (по крайней мере, `GetHashCode()`) будут вызываться дважды. Вкупе с избыточными разбиениями внутри этих методов картина получается нерадостная.

Можно пойти по другому пути, например, заранее разбить строки:

```
var splittedLst1 = lst1.Select(i => i.Split(';'));
var splittedLst2 = lst2.Select(i => i.Split(';'));
```

Затем получить разницу:

```
var comparer = new StringLengthEqualityComparer();
var rezList = splittedLst1
    .Except(splittedLst2, comparer)
    .Union(splittedLst2.Except(splittedLst1, comparer));
```

А при необходимости снова склеить строки:

```
foreach (var item in rezList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", item));
}
```

При таком подходе каждая строка будет разбита всего один раз, а код компаратора упростится:

```
class StringLengthEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        return x[1] == y[1] && x[2] == y[2];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string[] obj)
    {
        var hashcode = obj[1].GetHashCode();
        hashcode = hashcode * 31 + obj[2].GetHashCode();
        return hashcode;
    }
}
```

Если вы ожидаете строки разной длины (в смысле количества колонок), то нужно изменить компаратор таким образом, чтобы он корректно работал со строками разной длины.

Провел небольшой тест для сравнения производительности. В качестве тестовых данных склеил 10000 раз приведенные вам двухстрочники. Разница в результатах при этом получилась следующая:

> Radzhab: 332ms
>
> andreycha: 63ms

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написали в комментариях, лучше отказаться от `IEqualityComparer`, т.к., имхо, это попытка заставить кота лаять. У нас единицы информации — это "ячейки", т.е. слова конкретные, оперирование строками с этими словами порождает неудобные и багоопасные конструкции с прямым индексированием (кстати, легковесное в теории сравнение превратилось в 4-кратный вызов разбиения строки на подмассив; даже по алгоритму достаточно двух раз), что собственно ни к чему, если изначально всё разбить на слова. Т.е. в чём оптимизация, если выделяется больше памяти, больше операций и прямые индексы?

Сперва, на мой взгляд надо подготовить строки, т.е. в нашем случае можно всё загнать просто в двумерный массив строк, и все операции производить в нём, с отдельными словами.

Comment: Компаратор в данном случае весьма удобен, поскольку при его использовании логика получения уникальных строк пишет в одну строчку.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void GetUnion(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2)
{
    // List для результата
    List<string> lstUnion = new List<string>();
    foreach (string value in lst1)
    {
        string valueColumn1 = value.Split(';')[0];
        string valueColumn2 = value.Split(';')[1];
        string valueColumn3 = value.Split(';')[2];

        // Ищем совпадения, есть ли valueColumn2 и valueColumn3 в lst2 во 2-й и 3-й колонке, 
        // С 1-й и 2-й не перепутаем, 
        // ";russia;japan" - такая последовательность со знаком ';' в начале
        // может быть только если текст начинается со второй колонки.
        string result = lst2.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(";" + valueColumn2 + ";" + valueColumn3));

        if (result != null) // если совпадения есть
        {
            if (!lstUnion.Contains(result)) // и если значение уже не добавлено
            {
                lstUnion.Add(result);
                MessageBox.Show(result); // для проверки
            }                   
        }
    }
// В итоге в lstUnion одно значение - "spain;russia;japan"
}
```

Comment: *В итоге в lstUnion одно значение - "spain;russia;japan"* -- а требуется уникальные элементы найти.

Comment: То есть, сначала уникальные значения из lst1, а потом уникальные значения из lst2? В чём тогда сравнения двух файлов?

Comment: Если так, то просто сравнивать уже с lstUnion, если нет значения, то добавляем. Сначала `string result = lstUnion.FirstOrDefault(s => s.!Contains(";" + valueColumn2 + ";" + valueColumn3));` и так прогнать для lst1 и lst2

Answer (score 0):

1. Открываешь .csv как двумерный массив данных с помощью:

[Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel / CSV файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

2. Сравниваешь сначала по количеству ячеек в массивах, а потом если оно одинаковое, то по нутрянке ячеек двумя `foreach` (один во втором).

:)