# Методы сравнения ссылочных классов в .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Ранее считал, что переопределять Equals для своих классов можно и нужно. Но натолкнулся на иную информацию, что переопределение может привести к проблемам с некоторыми коллекциями.

1. Когда следует переопределять `object.Equals()` для своих классов?
2. Неужели, если хочется сравнить на эквивалентность согласно сущности два объекта своих классов, нужно создавать отдельный метод?
3. А как быть со сторонними классами? Получается они не поставляют средств сравнения на эквивалентность сущностей?

Что я понимаю под эквивалентностью сущностей. Допустим есть класс

```
public class Country
{ 
     public Country (string name)
     {
          this.name = name;
     }
     private readonly string name;
     public string Name { get {return name;}}
}

public void Main()
{
      var c1 = new Country("Россия");
      var c2 = new Country("Россия");
}
```

так вот c1 и с2 для меня эквивалентны, т.к. не может быть двух стран в моём мире, с одинаковым названием. Просто так получилось, что мы создали два экземпляра, но они идентичны по своей сути..

Comment: «...что переопределение может привести к проблемам с некоторыми коллекциями» — а вот тут нельзя ли подробнее? Никогда не слыхал о подобных проблемах.

Comment: Более полно, чем это сделал VladD, ответ дать не могу. А посему предлагаю вам ознакомиться с его обзором ["целого зоопарка методов сравнения объектов в C#"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-object-equals-%D0%B2-c?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Как известно, .NET по умолчанию [сравнивает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454619/106) объекты ссылочных типов *по ссылкам*, а объекты значимых типов -- *побитово* (читай, по значению).

К чему это приводит в вашем примере? К тому, что `c1` и `c2` считаются неравными. С т.з. бизнес-логики вы правильно заметили, что они равны, однако среда ничего не знает о бизнес-логике.

Отсюда выводы:

1. Метод `Equals()` надо переопределять там, где требуется, чтобы объекты считались равными по какому-то определенному правилу. В частности, это нужно, когда вы используете объекты типа в качестве ключей словаря, элементов хэш-сета, а также в качестве элемента какой-либо коллекции и вызываете метод `Contains()`. Также стоит заметить, что в пару к `Equals()` нужно переопределять и метод [`GetHashCode()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198504).
2. Да, нужно. Потому что правила равенства двух объектов одного типа -- это, грубо говоря, бизнес-правила, то, что относится к вашему приложению. Среда исполнения о них ничего не знает, но о них знаете вы как разработчик.
3. Для кастомного сравнения экземпляров сторонних классов используется интерфейс `IEqualityComparer<T>` и его реализации. В BCL включены некоторые готовые реализации (например, для сравнения строк без учета регистра). В большинстве случаев вам [потребуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560359/10) создавать свой компаратор.

Answer (score 9):

1. Стоит переопределять `object.Equals()` в том случае, если для экземпляров вашего класса есть реально существующий метод определения эквивалентности, общий для всего кода приложения. При переопределении `object.Equals()` обязательно стоит переопределять и метод `object.GetHashCode()`, причем так, чтобы для эквивалентных объектов `GetHashCode()` возвращал  одинаковое значение.
2. Нет, переопределение `object.Equals()` - не единственный доступный метод. Если нужно задать определение эквивалентности в одном конкретном случае, а не по всему приложению - то можно использовать стороннее сравнение через реализацию [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx). Почти все стандартные коллекции позволяют использовать `IEqualityComparer<T>` - либо как параметр конкретного метода поиска, или как параметр конструктора коллекции.
3. Для сторонних классов - см. 2.

Comment: Так же, рекомендую прочесть статью о том, как работает GetHashCode():
https://habrahabr.ru/post/188038/

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestsComponents
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс для тестирования методом рефлексии.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ReflectionComparer
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  record Result
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Boolean">Результат операции, где "false" - экземпляры отличаются и "true" - экземпляры классов совпали</param>
        /// <param name="Message">Информационное сообщение о подробной информации</param>
        public record Result(Boolean Boolean, String Message);
        /// <summary>
        /// record MemberInfoAndMeaning
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Member">Краткая информация о поле или свойстве класса в виде: "Тип - Имя"</param>
        /// <param name="Meaning">Значение поля или свойства</param>
        public record MemberInfoAndMeaning(String Member, Object Meaning);
        /// <summary>
        /// Метод тестирования на основе рефлексии. Принимает два объекта, а так же коллекции из объектов.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj1">Object который принимает первый элемент для сравнения.</param>
        /// <param name="obj2">Object который принимает второй элемент для сравнения.</param>
        /// <param name="virtual_or_not">Включить поиск по элементам с модификатором "виртуальный" по умолчанию стоит  false.</param>
        /// <param name="to_lower">Отвечает за сравнивание названий полей или свойств с приоритетом к реестру, по умолчанию стоит false.</param>
        /// <returns>Возвращает record "Result", где "Boolean" результат операции, и "Message" сообщение о замечаниях (С коллекциями при несовпадении возвращает "Коллекции классов совпали!")</returns>
        public static Result ReflectionEquals(Object obj1, Object obj2, Boolean virtual_or_not = false, Boolean to_lower = false)
        {
            List<String> remarks = new();

            if (obj1.GetType().IsClass && obj2.GetType().IsClass || obj1 is IEnumerable && obj2 is IEnumerable)
            {
                Type type1;
                Type type2;

                if (obj1 is ICollection enumerable_obj1 && obj2 is ICollection enumerable_obj2)
                {
                    foreach (Object variable_obj1 in enumerable_obj1)
                    {
                        //Экземпляр
                        obj1 = variable_obj1;
                        //Типы
                        type1 = variable_obj1.GetType();
                        Int32 count = 1;
                        foreach (Object variable_obj2 in enumerable_obj2)
                        {
                            //Экземпляр
                            obj2 = variable_obj2;
                            //Типы
                            type2 = variable_obj2.GetType();
                            (Boolean boolean, _) = GettingTypes(
                                obj1: obj1,
                                obj2: obj2,
                                type1: type1,
                                type2: type2,
                                remarks: remarks,
                                virtual_or_not: virtual_or_not,
                                to_lower: to_lower);
                            if (!boolean && enumerable_obj2.Count == count)
                            {
                                return new Result(Boolean: false, Message: "Класс не был найден в коллекции!");
                            }
                            else if (!boolean && enumerable_obj2.Count != count)
                            {
                                remarks.Clear();
                            }
                            else if (boolean)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                    }

                    return new Result(Boolean: true, Message: "Коллекции классов совпали!");
                }
                else
                {
                    type1 = obj1.GetType();
                    type2 = obj2.GetType();
                    //ищу поле и свойство
                    return GettingTypes(
                        obj1: obj1,
                        obj2: obj2,
                        type1: type1,
                        type2: type2,
                        remarks: remarks,
                        virtual_or_not: virtual_or_not,
                        to_lower: to_lower);
                }
            }
            //Простые типы
            else
            {
                if (obj1.Equals(obj: obj2))
                {
                    return new Result(Boolean: true, Message: "Значения равны!");
                }
                else
                {
                    return new Result(Boolean: false, Message: $"Значение в obj1: {obj1}  и значение в obj2: {obj2}  не совпали!");
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Метод для получения имени элемента и значения.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj1">Экземпляр первого класса в котором ведем поиск.</param>
        /// <param name="obj2">Экземпляр второго класса в котором ведем поиск.</param>
        /// <param name="type1">Полученный тип первого экземпляра.</param>
        /// <param name="type2">Полученный тип второго экземпляра.</param>
        /// <param name="remarks">Список ошибок.</param>
        /// <param name="virtual_or_not">Включить поиск по элементам с модификатором "виртуальный" по умолчанию стоит  false.</param>
        /// <param name="to_lower">Отвечает за сравнивание названий полей или свойств с приоритетом к реестру, по умолчанию стоит false.</param>
        /// <returns>Возвращает record "Result", где "Boolean" результат операции, и "Message" сообщение о замечаниях (С коллекциями при несовпадении возвращает "Коллекции классов совпали!")</returns>
        private static Result GettingTypes(Object obj1, Object obj2, Type type1, Type type2, List<String> remarks, Boolean virtual_or_not, Boolean to_lower)
        {
            MemberTypes[] member_types = { MemberTypes.Field, MemberTypes.Property };

            List<MemberInfoAndMeaning> member_infos_type1 = new();
            List<MemberInfoAndMeaning> member_infos_type2 = new();

            foreach (MemberInfo member_info in type1.GetMembers().Where(predicate: m => member_types.Contains(value: m.MemberType)).ToList())
            {
                Object meaning = null;

                try
                {
                    if (type1.GetProperty(name: member_info.Name)!.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual == virtual_or_not)
                    {
                        switch (member_info.MemberType)
                        {
                            //Свойства
                            case MemberTypes.Property:
                                {
                                    meaning = type1.GetProperty(name: member_info.Name)?.GetValue(obj: obj1);
                                    break;
                                }
                            //Поле
                            case MemberTypes.Field:
                                {
                                    meaning = type1.GetField(name: member_info.Name)?.GetValue(obj: obj1);
                                    break;
                                }
                        }

                        String member;
                        member = to_lower ? member_info.ToString().ToLower() : member_info.ToString();
                        member_infos_type1.Add(item: new MemberInfoAndMeaning(Member: member, Meaning: meaning));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            }

            foreach (MemberInfo member_info in type2.GetMembers().Where(predicate: m => member_types.Contains(value: m.MemberType)).ToList())
            {
                Object meaning = null;

                try
                {
                    if (type2.GetProperty(name: member_info.Name)!.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual == virtual_or_not)
                    {
                        switch (member_info.MemberType)
                        {
                            //Свойства
                            case MemberTypes.Property:
                                {
                                    meaning = type2.GetProperty(name: member_info.Name)?.GetValue(obj: obj2);
                                    break;
                                }
                            //Поле
                            case MemberTypes.Field:
                                {
                                    meaning = type2.GetField(name: member_info.Name)?.GetValue(obj: obj2);
                                    break;
                                }
                        }

                        String member;
                        member = to_lower ? member_info.ToString().ToLower() : member_info.ToString();
                        member_infos_type2.Add(item: new MemberInfoAndMeaning(Member: member, Meaning: meaning));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // ignored
                }

            }

            if (member_infos_type1.Count >= member_infos_type2.Count)
            {
                Examination(member_infos_type1: member_infos_type1, member_infos_type2: member_infos_type2, remarks: remarks, type1: type1, type2: type2);
            }
            else
            {
                Examination(member_infos_type1: member_infos_type2, member_infos_type2: member_infos_type1, remarks: remarks, type1: type2, type2: type1);
            }

            if (remarks.Count > 0)
            {
                String message = remarks.Aggregate(seed: String.Empty, func: (current, remark) => current + "  Замечание: " + remark);
                return new Result(Boolean: false, Message: message);
            }
            else
            {
                return new Result(Boolean: true, Message: "Все элементы и их значения были найдены!");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Метод для сравнения имен элементов и их значений.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="member_infos_type1">Коллекция (имя - значение) экземпляры меняются местами от количества найденных полей и значений.</param>
        /// <param name="member_infos_type2">Коллекция (имя - значение) экземпляры меняются местами от количества найденных полей и значений.</param>
        /// <param name="remarks">Список ошибок для заполнения.</param>
        /// <param name="type1">Тип экземпляра класса</param>
        /// <param name="type2">Тип экземпляра класса</param>
        private static void Examination(List<MemberInfoAndMeaning> member_infos_type1, List<MemberInfoAndMeaning> member_infos_type2, List<String> remarks, Type type1, Type type2)
        {
            foreach ((String member, Object meaning) in member_infos_type1)
            {
                for (Int32 count_index = 0; count_index < member_infos_type1.Count; count_index++)
                {
                    //проверяем Тип - Имя свойства или поля
                    if (member == member_infos_type2[index: count_index].Member)
                    {
                        if (meaning != null)
                        {
                            //проверяем object по фактическим значениям
                            if (meaning.Equals(obj: member_infos_type2[index: count_index].Meaning))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                remarks.Add(item: $"Элемент: {member} был найден! Но значение не совпало! Значения: {meaning} в {type1.Name} и {member_infos_type2[index: count_index].Meaning ?? "NULL"} в {type2.Name}");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (member_infos_type2[index: count_index].Meaning != null)
                            {
                                remarks.Add($"Элемент: {member} был найден! Но значение не совпало! Значения: {"NULL"} в {type1.Name} и {member_infos_type2[index: count_index].Meaning} в {type2.Name}");
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (member_infos_type2.Count == count_index + 1)
                        {
                            remarks.Add(item: $"Элемент: {member} с значением: {meaning} не был найден в экземпляре: {type2.Name}");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]