# Вопрос связанный с Equals C#

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему метод Object.Equals() возвращает false, если по сути у них одно и тоже значение?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563090/220553

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом

Answer (score 0):

Метод `Object.Equals` не знает ничего об особенностях реализации вашего класса `Test`. Он просто проверяет совпадение указателя на текущий объект и на переданный в него в качестве параметра.

Что бы у вас заработало как ожидается, вам нужно реализовать свой вариант метода `Equals`
Например так:

```
   public override bool Equals(Object obj)
   {
      if ((obj == null) || !this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
      {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         Test o = (Test) obj;
         return (x == o.x);
      }
   }
```

Так же рекомендую почитать информацию о методе [equals в MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0). Там очень подробно разобрано.